# What is the best way to measure search quality on site?

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search

I have site which is rely on search and I want to select single metric to use for search ranking experiments. What is the state of art metric for real live site.

"Real life" means I can't create golden standard and ask judges to rank results per query. 
I'm thinking about "clicks per search" as a main measure.

Comment: this is a tough question! :-)

Comment: I hope not everyone do this. The are a lot of sites which rely on search(not only google and bing, a lot of small sites and startups as well) and all of them do some experimentation and have agreed on some measure to check their relevance.